# Why does the instance method "protected_class_method" not exist for the "Module" class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Why does the instance method "protected_class_method" not exist for the "Module" class in Ruby, while the "public_class_method" and "private_class_method" instance methods do exist for the "Module" class?

This does not follow the pattern of the "private", "protected", and "public" instance methods all being defined for the "Module" class.

Comment: The difference between "private" and "public" depends on who's asking, but I'm not sure Ruby's reflection features properly categorize things all the time. "Protected" is just a way of saying "public for some, private for others".

Comment: [Matz says](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/245072), "If you understand the current behavior of protected visibility, you will understand why protected_class_method is not useful at all.
That's why we don't have it."

Answer (score 3):

For me, protected methods only make sense as instance methods.

Protected methods can be called by other instances of the same class.

```
class Student
  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end
  def older_than?(other)
    age > other.age
  end
  protected
  def age
    @age
  end
end
```

You can't directly call `age` on a Student instance

```
student1 = Student.new(21)

student1.age
NoMethodError: protected method `age' called for #<Student:0x514d058 @age=21>
```

But student1 can reference student2's age

```
student2 = Student.new(23)

student2.older_than?(student1)
 => true
```

So you can see how an instance's protected methods uniqueness is its ability to be referenced from another instance.

I can't see how you would use a class "protected method"... there's no scenario similar to the above.

EDIT

Thanks to Cary Swoveland completely messing with my mind, I realise you can do the following...

```
class Class
  def show_k(klass)
    klass.k
  end
  protected
  def k
    "This is k"
  end
end
```

Now if I do

```
String.k 
NoMethodError: protected method `k' called for String:Class
```

But if I do...

```
Integer.show_k(String)
=> "This is k"
```

Possible because classes are instances of the Class class.

I'm still not sure how I'd use this, but there you go.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's something I never considered before. Another question I have, is would a "protected_class_method" instance method on the "Module" class be made redundant by the method described in the EDIT made in the answer

Comment: `protected_class_method` still doesn't really make sense at a class level. The EDIT code created a protected method for ALL classes. Well, all classes that inherit from `Class`, which is by design pretty much all standard classes and the default for new classes. Whether you want that kind of global impact is debatable.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn The global impact would be undesirable IMHO in terms of the effects of the EDIT code. What I was thinking of was that if there was a "protected_class_method" instance method on the Module class that you could have a method (with a different implementation per each class) that could that only be invoked on classes by other classes perhaps to get metadata from the other class (but that's not useful IMO). Example: `class A; protected_class_method def self.m; :metadata; end; end` , `class B; def self.p(a); puts a.class.m; end; end` , where `A.m` would fail, but `B.p(A.new)` wouldn't.

Comment: I can only see this working with the modifications to `Class`.  It doesn't work with sub-classes (say you wanted to make a class ProtectedMethod and class Dog and class Cat that both inherit from ProtectedMethod) as protected methods in a sub-class are either instance methods or not protected.  So, no, don't think it's possible, someone smarter than me might find a way.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ok, but don't let it happen again in another eight years... :)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn **protected** can actually make a difference for class methods if you consider inheritance and explicit receivers (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879939/9290781).

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a class with one class method.

```
class K
  def self.k
    'hi'
  end
end
```

`def self.k` is just a shorthand way to define an *instance method* `k` on `K`'s singleton class. Let's do that and make it protected.

```
class K
  class << self
    protected def k
      puts 'hi'
    end
  end
end
```

We find that

```
K.k
  #=> NoMethodError: protected method `k' called for K:Class
```

The only way to invoke this method is (as with private methods) is with an implicit receiver:

```
class K
  k
end
  #=> 'hi'
```

By definition, a protected instance method defined on a singleton class could be invoked by an instance of the same class, but one can cannot create instances of singleton classes.

This behaviour is the same as private class methods, so it would serve no purpose to have protected ones as well.

Comment: The last line of this answer is not 100% correct if you consider inheritance and invoking class methods with an explicit receiver.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879939/9290781 for a possible use case of protected in the context of class methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between protected and private when declaring class methods (instance methods on a class's singleton class) if you consider inheritance and usage of explicit receivers in class methods. The following sample was tested using Ruby 2.5.

```
class A
  class << self
    protected def pro
      puts 'pro'
    end
  end
end

class B < A
  class << self
    # Works
    def explicit_receiver_test
      self.pro
    end

    # Works
    def implicit_receiver_test
      pro
    end
  end
end

begin
  B.pro # Throws: NoMethodError
rescue NoMethodError => e
  puts e.message # Prints: protected method `pro' called for B:Class
end
B.explicit_receiver_test # Prints: pro
B.implicit_receiver_test # Prints: pro

class C
  class << self
    private def pri
      puts 'pri'
    end
  end
end

class D < C
  class << self
    # Fails
    def explicit_receiver_test
      self.pri
    end

    # Works
    def implicit_receiver_test
      pri
    end
  end
end

begin
  D.pri # Throws: NoMethodError
rescue NoMethodError => e
  puts e.message # Prints: private method `pri' called for D:Class
end
begin
  D.explicit_receiver_test # Throws: NoMethodError
rescue NoMethodError => e
  puts e.message # Prints: private method `pri' called for D:Class
end
D.implicit_receiver_test # Prints: pri
```

Comment: Interesting! So now let's think how having a protected class method could be useful and also how to interpret Katz's remark (but for me that will be tomorrow, as I'm falling asleep).

Comment: That [comment](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/245072) was really old (in early 2007 before Ruby 1.9 was released) so Ruby must have changed since then. I have a feeling that he would say that it's not useful. You might want to check out this [blog post](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/09/07/protected-methods-and-ruby-2-0.html).